# Sequential continuity and limits connection proof

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I am having some trouble formulating a proof for this although it seems quite intuitive, so any help would be appreciated. If we have a function $f \colon (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ and $c \in (a,b)$ such that $$\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = l$$ then suppose there is also a sequence in the interval $(a,b)$, called $x_n$ and it converges to $c$. How can I show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)=l$$

Comment: the result is false! see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false, consider the function that is $1$ at $c$ and $0$ elsewhere and the constant $c$ sequence. If we have that $f$ is Continuous at $c$ then it is possible:

We have to prove that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that if $n\geq N$ then $|f(x_n)-l|<\epsilon$.

---

Suppose $\epsilon>0$ is given

Since $f$ is continuous there is a $\delta >0$ such that if $|x-c|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$.

Since $x_n$ converges to $c$ we can find an $N$ such that if $n\geq N$ then $|x_n-c|< \delta$.

Putting it together notice that if $n\geq N$ we have $|x_n-c|<\delta \implies |f(x_n)-l|<\epsilon$

Comment: You should fix the typo "$f$ is continuous"  and instead write $f$ has limit $l$ at $c$.

Comment: Good Point, then it is false

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately no one noticed this (in particular the accepted answer).  It can be rectified by assuming that the sequence $x_{n} $ does not take the value $c$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Otherwise we need continuity. My +1 delivered now.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.  Then by hypothesis, there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $x\in(a,b)$ and $|x-c|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$. Now use this $\delta>0$ and the fact that $\lim_nx_n=c$ to show that $\lim_nf(x_n)=l$.

EDIT: Thanks to the comments, I now see that this requires $l=f(c)$ (i.e. $f$ is continuous at $c$).  Otherwise, the statement is false.